# Getting no results when using v-on:click in IE11

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get v-on:click / @click to work in my project. It functions correctly in every browser except IE11.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button type="button" v-on:click="test">Log In {{ debug }}</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      debug: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    test() {
      console.log('hello')
      this.debug = 'hello'
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

Looking in IE11's dev console yields the following, but they're outputted after the page loads:

```
polyfill-eventsource added missing EventSource to window
SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught
eval code (204) (11,3)
```

Is there possibly something I'm overlooking that might prevent v-on:click to not work in IE11?

Comment: Unless its *absolutely crucial*, its usually not worth trying to get it to support IE. Major frameworks and companies have already stopped supporting it because of how broken and old it is.

Comment: @dantechguy I totally agree with you but it's something a client requested for their site because they have other customers that still insist in using IE11 for some reason

Comment: Does vue support IE11? any docs or issues on their end as a workaround?

Comment: are you using the vue cli?

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine I'm not sure. The project runs on a docker container.